# Authenticating to use Google Sheets REST api with Python

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use a local (mac) python program to append a row to a google sheet. I naively thought the snippet below would be sufficient:

```
import requests
url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEETID/values/Expenses!A1:D1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"
data = {
    "range": "Expenses!A1:D1",
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [
        [NEW ROW DATA]]
    ],
}


resp = requests.post(url, data)
```

I am getting the error:

> 401: "Request is missing required authentication credential.
>   Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
>   authentication credential.

I am not to sure how to set-up the authentication for the google sheets rest api.

Can anyone provide an example of how to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the sample python code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append).

```
"""
BEFORE RUNNING:
---------------
1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
   and check the quota for your project at
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
2. Install the Python client library for Google APIs by running
   `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
"""
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

# TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
# https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample
#
# Authorize using one of the following scopes:
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
credentials = None

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
spreadsheet_id = 'my-spreadsheet-id'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The A1 notation of a range to search for a logical table of data.
# Values will be appended after the last row of the table.
range_ = 'my-range'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# How the input data should be interpreted.
value_input_option = ''  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# How the input data should be inserted.
insert_data_option = ''  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

value_range_body = {
    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
}

request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

and also

Since you are working with the app that access data from the other user open this guide for [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#top_of_page) to know more about authentication credentials.